# Photoshop To CSS: How do you translate Fill to CSS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, css

I have a content box in photoshop with the background color #bc0018 with a 65% opacity and 50% fill.

I am able to translate the backgroundcolor and opacity part to this, but without the 50% fill the backgroundcolor looks different.

```
.content-box {
    background-color: rgba(188, 0, 24, 0.65); }
```

Any suggestions on also getting the proper "fill" in CSS?

**EDIT**

I did just divide the opacity by half and it appears to achieve the same effect as a 50% fill. Still, I would love to hear how other people do this? I definitely don't want to create an image just for this.

```
.content-box {
    background-color: rgba(188, 0, 24, 0.325); }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you want to do is set the opacity to 100% on your color in Photoshop. Screencapture and grab that actual color from the screencapture. You can then apply the color to your div and set the opacity to 65% and get the same color. Just a theory, anyways. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: What is the 50% against in photoshop? Simply transparent or transparent over a white background? #bc0018 at 50% over white translates to #dd7f8b. Over black it translates to #5e000c. Don't get me wrong I like RGBa values and their use, but if you can avoid them it's sometimes better for compatibility sake.

Comment: The problem I ran into using a simple hex value was that the text became transparent too. I used rbga as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/css-semi-transparent-background-but-not-text and http://www.css3.info/opacity_rgba_and_compromise/

Comment: Ahh yeah, CSS opacity effects all children as well. That makes more sense. If you actually want transparency in the web page, then RGBa is the best bet for a background color provided you're okay with lack of support in older browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply the opacity and fill opacity fractions, and you get the final opacity value. In your case this would be 0.65*0.5 = 0.325. So you're right that halving the opacity in this case works.

However, there are certain pitfalls that make a straightforward conversion from photoshop to CSS difficult. Fill opacity in PS will not affect drop shadows and such, but CSS opacity will also affect any analogous box-shadows you apply.

Answer (score 0):

rgba seems to be nothing more than regular rgb values

> { background-color:rgba(**154,201,40**,0.5); }

with the additional alpha/opacity value

> { background-color:rgba(154,201,40,**0.5**); }

So just paste the full opacity color values in the first three boxes (`rgb`), and set opacity for it in the last value e.g. 0.5 is 50% transparency...